# LinkedLIst indexOf recursive implementation

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

I'm having a hard time understanding how the recursion in following implementation of `indexOf()` of `LinkedList` works:

```
/**
 * Returns the position of the first occurrence of the 
 * given character in this list, or -1 if there is no 
 * such occurrence.
 */
public int indexOf(char c)
{
    if (this.head == null)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        return LinkedList.indexOf(c, this.head);
    }
}
private static int indexOf(char c, Node node)
{
    if (node.data == c)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if (node.next == null)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    int index = LinkedList.indexOf(c, node.next);
    if (index == -1)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1 + index;
    }
}
```

where `head` is the initial node ("link") in the list.

The `static indexOf()` method checks whether there's a data match in the head, and then whether there exists a next node. Assume both conditions are `false` (there's no data match and there exists a next node). Then `indexOf()` is called recursively on the next (second) node to perform the same checks. However, if both conditions are still `false`, what does it return to `int index` given that there's no `else` clause before `index` is declared? That doesn't seem legal.

When I stepped through it in the debugger, rather than returning anything it actually seems to do more recursive calls until one of the `if` conditions is met (either there's a data match or the end of the list is reached). But why would it do that? And then how is `1` being added to the `index` each time?

Comment: Hint: it might be a bit of work, but consider not using the debugger, but a piece of paper and a pen (on a "small scale" example). The best way to understand recursion is sometimes ... to do it manually for 5, 10 minutes. Just be sure that your starting data is well defined and meaningful.

Comment: @Jägermeister I agree that is very useful -- thank you -- though one must also understand some basic principles about how programs flow in order for that technique to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, if both conditions are still false, what does it return to int index given that there's no else clause before index is declared?

It will return nothing yet, it will enter another level of recursion:

```
indexOf(node) -> indexOf(node.next) -> indexOf(node.next.next) -> ...
```

Then when the conditions are met it finally returns a value and you start to come back from each recursion call you made before:

```
indexOf(node) <- indexOf(node.next) <- indexOf(node.next.next) <- ...
```

but doing so it will also add 1 to the index it is returning, therefore basically counting the recursion levels you reached which equal to the node number you reached which is the index you are looking for.

This diagram shows how the algorithm works when there is a match on the fourth node. The blue color indicates that we are entering recursion, the red color indicates that we are coming back from recursion (click the image to open it in its original size):

[image: Recursion]

This other diagram shows the order of execution of the instructions in case of a match on the third node (click the image to open it in its original size):

[image: Recursion, code execution]

Comment: I think I get it now. I was expecting there to be an error because neither of the `if` conditions (before `index` was declared) was met, but it seems that as long as there's an `else` clause at the end, it will keep entering another level of recursion until one of the `if` conditions are met.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about the `else`, the reason it enters another level of recursion is because of `int index = LinkedList.indexOf(c, node.next);`. Only when a `return` is reached you actually start getting the values for `index` and start doing `return 1 + index;`

Comment: What I was thinking was that normally if you were to define a method with return type `int` that only had two `if` clauses, you would get a compiler error, so why is it that in this case there's no compiler error when there's nothing to return to `index`? What rule determines that the compiler decides to enter another level of recursion instead?

Comment: The compiler sees that after `int index = LinkedList.indexOf(c, node.next);`  it will return something, so it is valid. The method does not end after the first 2 `if`, after that it does a recursive call, and then it actually return the result with the last 2 `if`.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand from your answer how the index value is properly set. Suppose the list holds `'H' 'E' 'L' 'L' 'O'`, and the passed argument is `'L'`. Then on second recursion call, there is a data match, and 0 is returned. But on the first recursion call, nothing is returned. Can you explain in a little more detail (either as a comment or editing your answer) how the index variable accumulates 1 for each recursion call?

Comment: I added a diagram. Click on it and take a look. In your example, remember that when the second recursion returns, you come back to the instruction `int index = LinkedList.indexOf(c, node.next);` of the first recursion call, therefore `index` will receive 0 and then proceed on the fourth `if` with `return 1 + index`, and so on.

Comment: Outstanding; thank you! Will take a few moments to digest this.

Comment: I understand now -- the key is knowing that the calling method is suspended while the called method runs, and that it returns its result to the calling method (of course, this principle is not specific to recursion).

Comment: Yes you got it, I added another diagram which is maybe more clear in that aspect.